# How to move to another full screen window of the same app

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I have two Safari windows, I put both of them into full screen. When I switch to another app (let's say Finder) by <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>, then the next time I switch back to Safari by <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>, I will be in the last full screen window that I was on.

How do I move from here to my other full screened Safari window? Is there any way to do this?

I know I can move to the right/left space by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>arrow</kbd>, but I have no idea where the other Safari window is (I'd have to guess).

EDIT: What I really meant is a keyboard shortcut, instead of Mission Control.

Answer (score 1):

Just going into the main Mission control window will solve this, it will give a nice summary like view of all your open (fullscreen) windows. Another way to switch between fullscreen windows is selecting the "Window" menu item or the Safari icon in your dock and choosing the right window from there.

**Edit**

If you want to use a keyboard shortcut to accomplish this you can use an application that binds a keyboard shortcut to an Apple script, like [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/). The next step is placing the script in your /Library/Scripts folder and adding a shortcut to the script in the FastScripts preferences.

I'm not really good with Apple scripts, but this is a sort of working script that I made:

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "Venster"
                tell menu "Venster"
                    click menu item 14
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

The big problem with this script is this:
The line `click menu item 14` will make the first window that you see when you click on the "Window" menu item active, and changing it to `click menu item 15` will make the second window active. However, obviously, this isn't included in my code, and I don't have the time to work on it today, so you can either ask someone else how to do this or wait until tomorrow.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. I really wanted a keyboard shortcut. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Are you ok with installing a little third party utility to run an Apple script when a keyboard shortcut is pressed?

Comment: I can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I use [TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/) for this.  It gives you an unlimited number of virtual desktops (each can be multi-monitor) and easy keyboard and visual navigation between them.  It basically does gracefully what Mission Control fails to do (I've had Mission Control disabled for a long time thanks to TotalSpaces).